# I'm getting errors for my own deprecated warnings

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm writing a private pod. (I don't think this matters, but thought I should put in the full information).

It's a library used by a couple of apps that I'm writing.

I've recently created some new routines (which make some older routines obsolete). So, I thought I'd mark some of the older routines with a deprecated flag, like this:

```
- (void) myOldRoutine  __attribute((deprecated("Use myNewRoutine instead")));
```

I'm expecting to get a **warning** when I compile, (just like other deprecation warnings I get). I'm just trying to add reminders to myself that I need to make newer calls in my client app.

However, instead of getting a warning, I'm getting an **error**.

I'm using other pods, some of which use older system APIs and always just generate warnings. Why does my use of this generate an error?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a couple underscores from the `attribute` declaration. It should be `__attribute__((deprecated("Use myNewRoutine instead")));`

Comment: thanks for the tip. what a dumb typo. In the meantime, I discovered that I also have a different problem, which I'll create a new SO case for. For some reason, when in Swift, this gets flagged as an error, even with the correct spelling.